# In this short py code, what triggers "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'" error? and how can I fix it

Tags: python

```
def z(*scores):
    a=min(scores)
    b=max(scores)
    c=sum(scores)/len(scores)
    print(f"min : {a}\nmax : {b}\naverage : {c}")

y = input("type all scores. ex)100, 90, 80, 70, 60\n")
x = y.split(", ")
x = list(map(int, x))
z(x)
```

when I run it, it triggers this error
What's the matter and how can I fix it

```
type all scores. ex)100, 90, 80, 70, 60
100, 90, 80, 70, 60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\____\Desktop\a.py", line 11, in <module>
    z(x)
  File "c:\Users\____\Desktop\a.py", line 5, in z
    c=sum(scores)/len(scores)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Your function takes an arbitrary number of arguments, which are passed to the function in a tuple, but you are passing a list as a single argument, which means that you're passing a tuple of list. Change to `z(*x)` when calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unpacking `scores`:

```
def z(*scores):
```

which makes it a tuple of lists (the value of `scores` will be `([100, 90, 80, 70, 60],)` inside the function). Remove the `*` to use the `scores` list as it is:

```
def z(scores):
```